# Use of a POS Tagger in Azure DevOps

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops

I am building a pipeline in azure DevOps, for my project I use a POS Tagger. It looks like this locally in my python script:

```py
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger

java_path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251"

os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

jar_fr = r"C:\Users\nameofuser\Documents\posttagger\stanford-postagger.jar"
model_fr = r"C:\Users\nameofuser\Documents\posttagger\models\french.tagger"
pos_tagger_fr = StanfordPOSTagger(model_fr, jar_fr, encoding='utf8')
```

I guess this is the part of my script I have to change if I want it to work on Azure Devops pipeline.

I don't know how to have this working in my Azure DevOps pipeline. Do I have to put it in requirements.txt (Java jre, jar file stanford-postagger.jar and french.tagger file)?

**UPDATE:**

I put the pos tagging files in the Azure Repos, the pos tagging seems working.

Comment: Just FYI: [stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/) is a successor to Stanford's java linguistics pipeline. It is pure Python, so easier to implement. You may want to give it a try. It also performs a lot better.

Comment: You should download the resources in your pipeline to a custom location, or, provide the resources in attached solid pipeline storage.

Comment: Thank you @marcuse

Comment: @LJRB Did the workaround provided by marcuse help you solve the issue?

Comment: I put the pos tagging files in the Azure Repos, the pos tagging seems working. But I don't know if it is the best method.

Comment: @LJRB Would you please convert your comment into an answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the workaround easily.